# How to compare the name of one file with a number?

Tags: python

I want to select the traces with the number that are more than 60.

Example of file name:  `bloc119_5950_6000.npy`
The number of this file is: `119`
But the error is it displays all  th number of all files without any comparison:

```
   def Extract_Number_Block(block):
        NbrBlock = block.split('bloc')[1].split('_')[0]
        return NbrBlock

    path_For_Numpy_blocks='/data/sas/blockData'

    for block in os.listdir(path_For_Numpy_blocks):
        NbrB= Extract_Number_Block(block)
        print(NbrB)
        A=60
        if NbrB>A:
            print(NbrB) 
        else:
            print('Erreur')
```

Comment: Can you show us what error you are receiving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function returns a string. A comparison occurs with int

```
def Extract_Number_Block(block):
    NbrBlock = block.split('bloc')[1].split('_')[0]
    return int(NbrBlock) #converting to int

path_For_Numpy_blocks='/data/sas/blockData'

for block in os.listdir(path_For_Numpy_blocks):
    NbrB= Extract_Number_Block(block)
    print(NbrB)
    A=60
    if NbrB>A:
        print(NbrB) 
    else:
        print('Erreur')
```

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing strings `NbrB` (part of the file-name) with integers `A`. That won't give you any meaningful comparison result (Python 2) or raise an Error (Python 3).

You could however convert the string to a number:

```
def Extract_Number_Block(block):
    NbrBlock = block.split('bloc')[1].split('_')[0]
    return int(NbrBlock)
```

Note the `int()` around the `NbrBlock` which will convert the string (if possible) to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to convert returned `NbrBlock` to integer as split will return as string. So you have A = 60 but your `NbrB` is '119' which is string. so Simply convert your `NbrB` or `NbrNBlock` to integer.

See below:

```
def Extract_Number_Block(block):
    NbrBlock = block.split('bloc')[1].split('_')[0]
    return int(NbrBlock)
```